# Zhang-Suen thinning algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, ocr

I have troubles with this kind of images in my implementation of ZS alghorithm:

```
........
.xx.....
..xx....
...xx...
....xx..
.....xx.
......x.
........
```

from description of algorithm(http://www.ppgia.pucpr.br/~facon/Afinamento/1984ZhangSuen.pdf) we need to perform two subiterations iteratively. After first subiteration I get the result below("," is a pixel set as background):

```
........
.,x.....
..xx....
...xx...
....xx..
.....xx.
......,.
........
```

Result after secong subiteration ("-" is a pixel set as background):

```
........
.,-.....
..xx....
...xx...
....xx..
.....x-.
......,.
........
```

And as you can see I get the same kind of structure of pixels but smaller than in input image:

```
........
........
..xx....
...xx...
....xx..
.....x..
........
........
```

After n iterations result is only two pixels. But It isn't good structure for this example as I think. I ask you is it a specific of ZS alghorithm or I have a wrong understanding of it. Thanks.